# Bootstrap unequal image height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started learning Bootstrap and one month into CSS. I am coding a page and I feel I have a poor understanding of pixels and responsive design.

So I have three images (.demo) in a section. The first image (.png) is 668x522 px and the other two (.jpeg) are 548x445 px. I am using col-md-4 for each image. I see that the tallest image ends up being shorter than the other two. You can [see my page here](http://trickyicky83.000webhostapp.com/). Notice how the leftmost image is shorter than the other two even though it has a greater height pixel-wise. My questions are

1. Why is the height shorter for the first image ? (I expected it to be tallest among the three). When I measure the other images in Chrome I see that their image height is 345 x 280px .How and who determines the rendered dimensions ?
2. I want all three to have the same height. I did `img.demo {height :280px ; }` and all images were lined up nicely but I understand this is not responsive. I tried `img.demo { height :73% }` (width of parent container col-md-4 is 380 px so height of 73% for img.demo should give 280px height to it. But settings a height in % to img.demo is not doing anything to it. Why is that ?
3. What would be the responsive way to have all images the same height ?

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><strong>GemniPro</strong></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <div class="jumbotron">
             <div class = "container">
                <div class = "row">
                     <div class = "col-md-6">
                            <h1>Capture <strong>Life</strong></h1>
                            <p>A fun and easy way to capture and share the moments you live for</p>
                            <a href= "#"><img class= "app-btn" src="img/icon_app_store.png"></a>
                            <a href= "#"><img class= "app-btn" src="img/icon_google_play.png"></a>
                        </div>
                     <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <img  class ="showcase" src = "img/site_phone.png" >
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>     
        </div> 
    </section>

    <section id = "middle">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class ="container">
                <div class = "col-md-4 ">
                    <img src  = "img/demo1.png" class="demo" >
                    <h3> Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lobortis tempus varius. Sed porttitor ex id lectus interdum tristique.</p>
                </div>
               <div class = "col-md-4 ">
                   <img src = "img/demo2.jpg" class="demo">
                   <h3> Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lobortis tempus varius. Sed porttitor ex id lectus interdum tristique.</p>
                </div>
               <div class = "col-md-4 demo">
                    <img src  = "img/demo3.jpg" class="demo">
                    <h3> Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lobortis tempus varius. Sed porttitor ex id lectus interdum tristique.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

strong {
    color:aqua ;
}

section#middle {
    padding:40px 0 40px 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    color :#fff;
    background: url("../img/site_showcase_bg.jpg");
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.jumbotron img.app-btn {
    height : 60px;
    width:40%

} 

.jumbotron h1 {
    margin-top:125px;
}

.jumbotron p {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.jumbotron img.showcase {
    width:75%;
}

#middle img.demo {
    width:100%;
    height:73%;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from the external website which images should be looked at, and it is possible that the images referred to are no longer on that site. Since the question is entirely reliant on this, the question cannot be regarded as self-contained, and thus it is off-topic. If you can reproduce an example of the issue (e.g. in a screenshot) and put it in the question itself, that would help save the question from being put on hold. Remember that we want questions to survive over the long term here, so "see my website" does not work when the website is fixed or amended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images maintain their aspect ratio if you do not apply any width or height. In case you apply both of them in such a way that the aspect ratio is greater than the original, the image gets distorted.

1. The height to width ratio of the first image is greater than the other 2 images which are equal in height and width. The more width will be, the less the height will be.
2. The percentage height is calculated with reference to the parent height. Since, the enclosing container of `.demo` does not have a height, defining a height in percentage has no effect.
3. Either take the images of the same size. Or

`.demo
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 280px;
   border: solid 1px #ccc;`

Or

`.demo
   max-width: 100%;`

There is not much difference in the height of all 3 images, so its safe to remove the border altogether. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first image is a little bit smaller because its aspect ratio is different from the other two:

The first image original size is: 668x552 | aspect ratio = 1.210

The other two are: 548x445 | aspect ratio = 1.231

They need to have the same aspect ratio or you can put them inside a div and display them as `background-size: contain`